# Tutorial help: Import name doesn't align with component name, still works

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am following the project on [github](https://github.com/burkeholland/react-cosmosdb.git) and working through personal modifications

It could probably be answered with google/documentation, but I don't know the right keywords to pull it in yet. One day, soon.

This doesn't line up with the file naming conventions I have seen.

`Heroes.js imports api.js. api.js` talks to the express backend via a proxy setting at the /api/* route. Problem is that the api.js file never declares an "api" component.

**How is it that api.js is exporting "heroService", yet when its being imported, its operating under "api"?** Is it because the file is named api.js and it defaults to that as the component name?

Heroes.js

```
import api from '../api';
//Example function
  handleDelete(event, hero) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    api.destroy(hero).then(() => {
      let heroes = this.state.heroes;
      heroes = heroes.filter(h => h !== hero);
      this.setState({ heroes: heroes });

      if (this.selectedHero === hero) {
        this.setState({ selectedHero: null });
      }
    });
  }
```

api.js

```
const baseAPI = '/api';    
const heroService = {
//example function


destroy(hero) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(`${baseAPI}/hero/${hero.id}`, { method: 'DELETE' })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => resolve(json))
        .catch(err => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }

export default heroService;
```

Answer (score 0):

**`api.js` is exporting a `default`.**

Since this is *not* a named export, the binding takes on the name that you specified upon `import`.

As you wrote `import api from '../api';`, you use `api.destroy()`.

If you wrote `import monkeys from '../api';`, you would use `monkeys.destroy()` instead.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import